# How can I make a scatter Plot with what I have?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
total_income_language = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('movie_facebook_likes')['gross'].sum())   
average_income_language = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('movie_facebook_likes')['gross'].mean()) 



d = {'mean':'Average Income','sum':'Total Income'}
df1 = df.groupby('movie_facebook_likes')['gross'].agg(['sum','mean']).rename(columns=d)

ax = df1.plot.bar()
ax.set(xlabel='Facebook Likes', ylabel='Dollar Values(Gross)')
```

So, the code I have above does a good job ploting a bargraph. But When I tried to make it into a scatter plot by changing the .bar() to .scatter() It gives me the following error:

[image: Here's the error message]

What do I need to fix to make it a scatter plot?

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you, you need to specify `x` and `y` arguments which represent the coordinates of your points.

For example (assuming that there are `movie_facebook_likes` and `gross` columns in your DataFrame):

`ax = df1.plot.scatter(x='movie_facebook_likes', y='gross')`

See [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

> x, y : label or position, optional
>   Coordinates for each point.

Comment: I had tried that as well, but giving error, keyerror: 'movie_facebook_likes'

Comment: You should use actual column names.

Comment: Those are the actual column names from the data frame

Comment: Would you mind editing your code, and add a subset of your data frame (e.g. using `df.to_dict()` method so we can reproduce the steps?

Comment: @python_noob You should post the output in the above question, not links...